# What's the meaning of "plenty sweet enough"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> "Sweeter than honey" may be plenty sweet enough.

What's the meaning of "plenty sweet enough"?

I guess it means that "sweeter than honey" is too much of sweet.

Am I right? If I'm right, how is it so?

I don't think 'plenty sweet enough' connotes any negative meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Plenty sweet enough..**.

If something is *plenty sweet enough*, there's no need to make it even sweeter.  It's already quite sweet as it is.

Sweet enough = has sufficient sweetness.

Plenty sweet enough = has more than sufficient sweetness.

> Mom, can I put some more honey in my oatmeal?
>   -- No, it's plenty sweet enough.

"Plenty" there is an intensifying modifier, modifying "sweet enough".

Comment: In the oatmeal example you give, I'd paraphrase _plenty sweet enough_ as "sweet enough already," and not as "more than sufficiently sweet." The "more than" in your definition seems to imply that something is _too_ sweet, which I don't think is the case here.

Comment: Were that _my_ mother in the oatmeal scenario, she would have clarified whether she meant "excessively sweet" or "sufficiently sweet" through judicious use of an eyebrow.  (I can imagine "plenty sweet enough" being used both ways, with a fuzzy grey line between the two.)

Comment: @J.R. In my experience with this pattern, the implication is that the thing being described is not only adequate but perhaps a little more than was desired.  *Do you want the tuxedo to fit tighter? --No, it's plenty tight enough.*